# Program to see K-Means iteration by iteration?

Tags: r, machine-learning, cluster-analysis, data-mining, k-means

I'm working on K-Means using R, but I can't get the intermediate steps before the final categories and centroids. Is there any options in R to get the intermediate centroids of every iteration? Or should I use another software?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `iter.max=1` to execute one iteration at a time.